# Delete everything before the word given by the list except the word given in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| cure center state hospital | hospital |
| state polyclinic cure center | center |
| state hospital main dispancer | dispancer |
| first hospital number one | hospital |

I also have a list of different types of medical institutuons:

```
types_list <- c("hospital", "center", dispancer", "polyclinic")
```

What I would like to do is delete everything before the type from the list if it does not coincide with the type column.

The desired output is:

| Name | Type | Name after |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cure center state hospital | hospital | state hospital |
| state polyclinic cure center | center | cure center |
| state hospital main dispancer | dispancer | main dispancer |
| first hospital number one | hospital | first hospital number one |

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Data for the dataframe:

```
Name <- c("cure center state hospital","state polyclinic cure center","state hospital main dispancer","first hospital number one",)
Type <- c("hospital", "center", "dispancer", "hospital")
```

Comment: The last one, why not `first hospital`? You did not delete `number one`

Comment: Your question is incoherent. Are you deleting `before` or `after`? Can you explain how `state polyclinic cure center` ends up being `cure center`??

Comment: Hi! Basically I have situations when there are 2 types of institutions in one string. I have a column with the type I need to leave for each string. However, if I have more than one institution I want to delete everything before the one I do not need to leave. In case when there is one institution nothing should be deleted.

Comment: in the first row, what if type was `center` instead of `hospital`? what would the result be??

Comment: what happens if you search for the strings in name after: like types_list <- c("state hospital", "cure center", main dispancer", "first hospital number one"). How many and which will then leave unrecognzied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first approximation, you could create a regular expression consisting of all types minus the one that is present in the `Type` column of each row and remove everything up until that word:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  name = c(
    "cure center state hospital",
    "state polyclinic cure center",
    "state hospital main dispancer",
    "first hospital number one"
  ),
  type = c("hospital", "center", "dispancer", "hospital")
)

types_list <- c("hospital", "center", "dispancer", "polyclinic")

remove_before <- function(name, type) {
  types_regex <- setdiff(types_list, type) |> str_flatten(collapse = "|")
  pattern <- str_c(".*", "(", types_regex, ")\\s+?")
  str_remove(name, pattern)
}

df |> 
  mutate(new = remove_before(name, type), .by = type)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   name                          type      new                      
#>   <chr>                         <chr>     <chr>                    
#> 1 cure center state hospital    hospital  state hospital           
#> 2 state polyclinic cure center  center    cure center              
#> 3 state hospital main dispancer dispancer main dispancer           
#> 4 first hospital number one     hospital  first hospital number one
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hello @dufei ! Unfortunatelly the code does not work because R does not recognize the |> symbol when I ran the code. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, you should update your R version (should be at least version 4.1). Alternatively you can rewrite `df |> mutate(...)` as `mutate(df, ...)`. You can also use `%>%` instead of `|>` if you have loaded the Tidyverse package. But really, just update your version of R ✌️